# View more Jobs -> 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, broken-link, site-ads

Clicking either of these links:
[image]

Takes me to a 404 page:
[image]

Does it do that for anyone else? Is it because I wasn't logged in?

Comment: No, When I clicked on view more jobs it works perfectly while I was logged in or logged out.

Comment: I can confirm I can reproduce it, based on the URL in your screenshot.  It looks like there are url params getting added before the '?', which would cause issues.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for flagging this. It was indeed affecting only the header and footer links of the C# jobs ads.

An update that fixes this issue has been released.